# Different behavior in C regex VS C++11 regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need a code that splits math-notation permutations into its elements, lets suppose this permutation:

[image: Permutation]

The permutation string will be:

> "(1,2,5)(3,4)" or "(3,4)(1,2,5)" or "(3,4)(5,1,2)"

The patterns i've tried are this:

- `([0-9]+[ ]*,[ ]*)*[0-9]+` for each permutation cycle. This would split the `"(1,2,5)(3,4)"` string in two strings `"1,2,5"` and `"3,4"`.
- `([0-9]+)` for each element in cycle. This would split each cycle in individual numbers.

When i've tried this patterns in [this page](http://regexpal.com/) they work well. And also, i've used them with the C++11 regex library with good results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <regex>

void elements(const std::string &input)
{
    const std::regex ElementRegEx("[0-9]+");

    for (std::sregex_iterator Element(input.begin(), input.end(), ElementRegEx); Element != std::sregex_iterator(); ++Element)
    {
        const std::string CurrentElement(*Element->begin());
        std::cout << '\t' << CurrentElement << '\n';
    }
}

void cycles(const std::string &input)
{
    const std::regex CycleRegEx("([0-9]+[ ]*,[ ]*)*[0-9]+");

    for (std::sregex_iterator Cycle(input.begin(), input.end(), CycleRegEx); Cycle != std::sregex_iterator(); ++Cycle)
    {
        const std::string CurrentCycle(*Cycle->begin());
        std::cout << CurrentCycle << '\n';

        elements(CurrentCycle);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string input("(1,2,5)(3,4)");

    std::cout << "input: " << input << "\n\n";

    cycles(input);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output compiling with Visual Studio 2010 (10.0):

```
input: (1,2,5)(3,4)

1,2,5
    1
    2
    5
3,4
    3
    4
```

But unfortunately, i cannot use the C++11 tools on my project, the project will run under a Linux plataform and it must be compiled with gcc 4.2.3; so i'm *forced* to use the C regex library in the `regex.h` header. So, using the **same patterns** but with different library i'm getting different results:

[Here is](http://ideone.com/L8ktOb) the test code:

```
void elements(const std::string &input)
{
    regex_t ElementRegEx;
    regcomp(&ElementRegEx, "([0-9]+)", REG_EXTENDED);

    regmatch_t ElementMatches[MAX_MATCHES];
    if (!regexec(&ElementRegEx, input.c_str(), MAX_MATCHES, ElementMatches, 0))
    {
        int Element = 0;

        while ((ElementMatches[Element].rm_so != -1) && (ElementMatches[Element].rm_eo != -1))
        {
            regmatch_t &ElementMatch = ElementMatches[Element];
            std::stringstream CurrentElement(input.substr(ElementMatch.rm_so, ElementMatch.rm_eo - ElementMatch.rm_so));
            std::cout << '\t' << CurrentElement << '\n';

            ++Element;
        }
    }

    regfree(&ElementRegEx);
}

void cycles(const std::string &input)
{
    regex_t CycleRegEx;
    regcomp(&CycleRegEx, "([0-9]+[ ]*,[ ]*)*[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED);

    regmatch_t CycleMatches[MAX_MATCHES];
    if (!regexec(&CycleRegEx, input.c_str(), MAX_MATCHES, CycleMatches, 0))
    {
        int Cycle = 0;

        while ((CycleMatches[Cycle].rm_so != -1) && (CycleMatches[Cycle].rm_eo != -1))
        {
            regmatch_t &CycleMatch = CycleMatches[Cycle];
            const std::string CurrentCycle(input.substr(CycleMatch.rm_so, CycleMatch.rm_eo - CycleMatch.rm_so));
            std::cout << CurrentCycle << '\n';

            elements(CurrentCycle);
            ++Cycle;
        }
    }

    regfree(&CycleRegEx);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cycles("(1,2,5)(3,4)")
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is the same as using C++11 regex, but the real ouput was:

```
input: (1,2,5)(3,4)

1,2,5
    1
    1
2,
    2
    2
```

Finally, the questions are:

- Could someone give me a hint about where i'm misunderstanding the C regex engine?
- Why the behavior is different in the C regex vs the C++ regex?

Comment: I haven't read all of this yet, but can I just first point out that the first thing you're missing is that regular expressions are *not* good grammatical processing tools. What you *should* use for reading maths like this is a Lexer/Parser. May I suggest having a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)? Just to be clear, that's not to say throw away your work so far and start over, but I think it's good to know what tools are out there and what's the right tool for the job.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot catch multiple things in a single capturing group. You will always just get the capture of the first or last time the group is used (depending on the engine). You should rather get the full `1,2,5`, then use a `split` function with `,` as the delimiter and then join it together with `\n\t`.

Comment: You have some very odd bits of regex scattered around here. For example `[ ]*` (`[...]` is essentially an `or`, but you're only putting a single character there, use `" *"` or `"\\s*"` (whitespace)). I also think you'd be better off capturing everything between brackets and splitting on `,`: `"\\(([\\d\\s,]*)\\)"` and split on `"\\s*,\\s*"`. If you know you won't have any whitespace you can ignore the `\\s`.

Comment: if you can use boost, and use regex from there...

Comment: "*so i'm forced to use the C regex library in the `regex.h` header.*" To echo @NoSenseEtAl, see [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) or [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the output of `regexec`.  The `pmatch` buffer (after `pmatch[0]`) is filled with *sub-matches* of the regex, not with consecutive matches in the string.

For example, if your regex is `[a-z]([+ ])([0-9])` matched against `x+5`, then `pmatch[0]` will reference `x+5` (the whole match), and `pmatch[1]` and `pmatch[2]` will reference `+` and `5` respectively.

You need to repeat the `regexec` in a loop, starting from the end of the previous match:

```
int start = 0;
while (!regexec(&ElementRegEx, input.c_str() + start, MAX_MATCHES, ElementMatches, 0))
{
    regmatch_t &ElementMatch = ElementMatches[0];
    std::string CurrentElement(input.substr(start + ElementMatch.rm_so, ElementMatch.rm_eo - ElementMatch.rm_so));
    std::cout << '\t' << CurrentElement << '\n';
    start += ElementMatch.rm_eo;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally right! (while you where writing the code i was doing some tests) [it works fine now](http://ideone.com/YlzH93). **new question** So i guess that the buffer of `ElementMatches` isn't needed, you can call the `regexec` function with just one element, isn't it?